# Fetching records which have either of two values in an array column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array_agg column in postgresql which has values like these:

```
"{Metabolic/Endocrinology}"
"{Cardiovascular}"
"{Oncology}"
"{Autoimmune/Inflammation}"
```

Basically a string variable being array_agg by an id.

Now I want to fetch all records from this table where either of Oncology or Autoimmune/Inflammation is present.

I am doing something like this but I am not sure why it is throwing an error.

```
select * from Table where id = ANY('{Oncology,Autoimmune/Inflammation}')
```

It throws the following error.

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] = text
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 67
```

Please note I have also used ::TEXT [] and it still gives an error.

Comment: In future it's helpful if you provide sample data as `create table` and `insert` statements, so it's not necessary to dummy up data for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the array-overlaps operator `&&`.

See [array operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

e.g.

```
select * from (
  VALUES
  (ARRAY['Oncology','Pediatrics']),
  (ARRAY['Autoimmune/Inflammation','Oncology']),
  (ARRAY['Autoimmune/Inflammation']),
  (ARRAY['Pediatrics']),
  (ARRAY[]::text[])
) "Table"(id)
where id && ARRAY['Oncology','Autoimmune/Inflammation'];
```

By the way, I suggest using the SQL-standard `ARRAY[...]` constructor where possible.

Also, it's almost certainly a *terrible* idea to have an `id` column (presumably a `primary key`, if not, the name is confusing) defined as an array type.

Comment: Moreover, && operation can be supported by GIN index: create index on "Table" using gin(id).